# file upload using progress element in HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html

I am using progress element while displaying the progress of a file upload in javascript.
But the problem that I am facing is it is not completely loading huge file.when I checked evet.total attribute it gives the total size of the file in bytes.But when it loads physically event.loaded attribute loads only 70 to 75 %.So I want to know is there any pre-requisite when use progress event? Has anybody faced this kind of issue before?.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that the `progress` element is just not well supported yet?

Comment: @matthewpavkov,searched in MDC also regarding the same, but did not get any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a ticket raised as bug in FireFox.The details as follows:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=641287

Answer (score 0):

Are you use a `FileReader` to upload the file? If you are, you can define the `.onloadend` method of your `FileReader` which will trigger when the file is done reading.

Read the docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader

Comment: I tried loading bigger files of size greater than 50 MB.But it is trying to load maximum upto 50 MB.Not more than that. .onloadend method is gettinf triggered upon reading maximum upto 50 MB.This is what observed in my system.Not sure with other machines.I Is there any restriction on file size while reading a huge file

Comment: @UNNI: Not that I know of, but each browser implementation probably have it's own limits.